What do the words "bond issue passes" in "bond issue passes council" mean?
In the movie "Chinatown" a part of the plot is a problem of a local council in L.A on whether to build a dam that will replace St. Francis Dam which had collapsed in the past. As a result, the city is having problems with its water supply. Later in the movie, you can see a headline on a newspaper held by the main character which states:
"Water Bond Issue Passes Council"
below there is a subheading:
"$10,000,000 Referendum To Go Before Public"
Seems pretty clear to me that "bond" here means:
a certificate issued by a government or a public company promising to repay borrowed money at a fixed rate of interest at a specified time.(Oxford Languages)
I think that the word "passes" means:

To be approved or adopted: The motion to adjourn passed. (American Heritage® Dictionary)

When it comes to the word "issue" I'm not so sure anymore. Seems to me like it could mean either:

a. The act of circulating, distributing, or publishing by a business, government, or organization: government issue of new bonds. (American Heritage® Dictionary)

But it could also mean:

an important topic or problem for debate or discussion.
"the issue of racism" (Oxford Languages)

It's either that the council [or the local/municipal government] approved the discussion on the issue of bonds being issued later in time or the issuance of the bonds itself. What is confusing to me is the subheading about the referendum. Is it that the council accepted it but gave the people the final say on the issue?

The word "issue" is used with this meaning:
a. The act of circulating, distributing, or publishing by a business, government, or organization: government issue of new bonds. (American Heritage® Dictionary)
In American local government, proposals for significant expenditure on projects like water supply systems, drainage, etc, have to successfully undergo two stages: 1. Scrutiny by the elected local government authority ('council'), 2. A referendum (vote) by the electors of the region.
You are correct that the council accepted it but gave the people the final say on the issue.
